# Pass a variable to dplyr::count in a loop

Tags: r, dplyr

I’m trying to run `dplyr::count()` on an arbitrary set of variables in one dataset. If I manually run `count()` once for each variable, I get the expected results. But when I try to put `count()` in a for loop to run it automatically for each variable in a set of variables, I got an error. It seems like the problem is in how I am passing the variable to `count()` within the for loop. I know that `count()` takes its variables unquoted, and for whatever reason R cannot tell that what I am passing it is a variable.

I’ve tried a number of things to fix this, including passing the variables as `data$var1`, `quo(var1)`, `enquo(var1)`, `var1`, `“var1”`, `quo(data$var1)`, and `enquo(data$var1)` as well as unquoting the iterator with `!!`. I also tried specifying the arguments to `count()` like `count(x=data, var=i)`, but this caused `count()` to return the total number of rows in data as the count for each iteration. If you have any ideas about what is causing the error or how I can fix it, I would very much appreciate hearing them!

Here is a minimal reproducible example that relies on the `lakers` dataset included with `lubridate`.

```
# This code requires some of the packages in tidyverse. 
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)


# results = empty data frame for filling with info from the count() command
results <- data.frame()

# mydata = the source data
myData <- lakers

# myCols = list of the names of columns I want to count()
myCols <- c("opponent", "game_type", "player", "period")


# Loop to count() every column in myCols automatically and store the results in 
# one giant tibble of vars (var) and counts (n)

for(i in myCols){
results <- bind_rows(results, count(x=myData, i))
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works:

```
myData[myCols] %>% tidyr::gather(var, value) %>% count(var, value)

# A tibble: 407 x 3
         var value     n
       <chr> <chr> <int>
 1 game_type  away 17153
 2 game_type  home 17471
 3  opponent   ATL   904
 4  opponent   BOS   886
 5  opponent   CHA   412
 6  opponent   CHI   964
 7  opponent   CLE   822
 8  opponent   DAL  1333
 9  opponent   DEN  1855
10  opponent   DET   845
# ... with 397 more rows
```

If you want to pass `myCols` in a tibbledish manner, you'll have to look up the rlang package.

Comment: Hmm, when I try running that line I get the error 
"Error in UseMethod("as.quoted") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.quoted' applied to an object of class "function""

Comment: @jozimck If you run it in a new R session with only the code in your question and this answer, is that what you see? It could be a versioning thing; I'm on dplyr 0.4.3 and R 3.3.3

Comment: Ah yes, then it works as shown above. Must have have cluttered my workspace with something. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 7):

From :https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/vignettes/programming.Rmd

If you have a character vector of variable names, and want to operate on them with a for loop, index into the special `.data` pronoun:

```
for (var in names(mtcars)) {
  mtcars %>% count(.data[[var]]) %>% print()
}
```